# Comparing ArrayList to String

Tags: java, arraylist

//My problem is that in the method canceledOrder the string [] waitingList[] is not being seen at least that is what I think.

```
public static String[] canceledOrder(String[] waitingList,String[] waitingList1,String []waitingList2,String[] waitingList3){//I've decided to pass these string [] hoping the string from the other methods will now be seen in canceledOrder();
            Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
            int option;
            System.out.println("Select the event you want to cancel :\n");
            events();
            option= in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Person on wait list is " + waitingList[name] );
            switch (option){

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Please enter your name:\n");
                canceledname = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("name:" + canceledname);



                for (String s : myStringList) {
                    if(s.equals(canceledname)){

                        s = waitingList[name];

                        System.out.println("The new name is\n" + s);

                        name++;
                    }
                    return s; // I want it to now return waitingList[name]
                }

                break;
```

Comment: What do you mean by compare? Of course, an `ArrayList` cannot be equal to a `String`?

Comment: Do you mean to check if the ArrayList contains the String?

Comment: i think you want to compare the element inside the `myStringList` m i right ? or if you want to compare whole `myStringList` to single `String variable` this is not possible.. the better way is to compare one by one element to `String variable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but did you want to loop through the arraylist to see if any values in the list equal `cancelledName`?

If so, you may want something like this

```
for (String s : myStringList) {
    if(s.equals(canceledname)){

        k = waitingList[name];

        System.out.println("The new name is" + k);

    name++;
    }
}
```

**Edit: with possible solution to problem**

```
// declare array of Attendees, capacity is 20
// I would rather use ArrayList, but it seems you're trying to use array
String attendees[] = new String[20];

// delcare wait list
String waitList[] = new String[2];

// declare int for tickets sold
int ticketsSold = 0;
// declare waitlist
int waitlistCount = 0;

// prompt buyers for purchase of tickets
// ticketsSold = ticketsSold +  1 or 2 depending on tickets
// if ticketsSold is 20 do not sell tickets and send to waiting list
// Do this until full

// if ticketsSold = 20
// prompt user to go on wait list
// if yes, ask how many tickets
// if tickets requested for waitlist exceeds current waitlist + tickets requested
       // System.out.println("Sorry, waitlist is full");
// else prompt for user name
String name = in.nextLine();
waitlist[waitListCount] = name;

// here's the part I think you're having problems with
// if person is deleted from attendees
// get name of person not attending
int i = 0;
while (!cancelledName != attendees[i]) {
    i++
}

// replace attendees index with waitlist Name
attendees[i] = waitlist[0];

// move the waitlist forward
waitlist[0] = waitlist[1];
waitlist[1] = null;
```

This is the best I can think of as far as logic.  If you logic is sound and looks similar to mine, just focus on the bottom portion, where I think you're having the most problems

Comment: Your piece of advice made the most sense to me but rather than printing the name I stored in waitingList[name]; it printed out null. I know the compiler should be able to pull out the information stored in waitingList[name]; because I set it as static.

Comment: Where/How do you declare and initialize `waitList[]`? And `name` in `waitingList[name];` must be a reference to an `int`.  `name` must be an `index` value, not a `String`, if that's what `name` is

Comment: Explain step by step what is it your actually trying to do, because I am very unclear.  All I know is you're trying to match `canceledName` with a value in `myStringList`.  But then what?

Comment: waitingList[] is a global string variable, and names of people goes into the the array,  name is declared as an int, I am using it as an index, correct.

Comment: `static` or not has nothing to do with why the data is null. It's null because there's no value in the index.  How are you populating the `waitingList` array?  Also, if it's an `ArrayList` and not an `array`, you have to extract the data by using the `get(index)` method. In your case, `waitingList.get(name)`.  But it seems like you're trying to use an `array`, right?

Comment: I think the most important question is how you're populating the array. You don't have that in your code.  That could indicate why you are getting null.  Edit your code to show the array declarations, initialization, and how you populate it.

Comment: I am getting the information that goes into waitingList[] from the user it is an input that goes in it, and the code for it is in a method. The code for the canceledname is outside the method in a switch statement, I believe that might be the cause.

Comment: so the `cancelledName`, is that what is supposed to be going into the `waitingList`? Because I don't what else it could be.

Comment: No, rather waitingList[] is suppose to take the place of canceledname in myStringlist

Comment: Can you edit your code to show everything you have, because I'm totally lost about what you're trying to here. But I do want to help you.  Or at the bottom of your code, put an edit that states STEP by STEP EXACTLY what you're trying to do.  The first is preferred, but second will work as well.

Comment: if(countingTickets == 0){
   if(name < 2){
    System.out.println("There are no longer any tickets available, would you like to be put on a waiting list? (1 = yes)");
    wait = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    if(wait == 1){
     System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
     waitingList[name] = in.nextLine();

     System.out.println(waitingList[name]);
     name++;
    }
   } else{
    System.out.println("The waiting list is full.");
   }

  }

Comment: I couldn't edit for some reason it kept requiring comments or some issue with indentation. The snippet of code above is where I'm drawing the information into waitingList[] the code is in a method.

Comment: What is this `if(name < 2)` supposed to do? This is implying that you only allow 2 names on the waitingList.

Comment: Also, at the Bottom of your code, can you PLEASE logically explain step by step, what is it you want your code to do, because without your original code, I still can't see what it is you're trying.  If I can understand the problem that this problem is supposed to perform/solve, I can give hints as to how to go about doing it.  I can't tell anything from snippets.  I'd rather give you example code that may help you solve your problem, then pick one thing here and there, that can be fixed, that may or may not solve your ultimate problem

Comment: I am working on this project that displays a menu for events, the event has a capacity and when that event is full you can be placed on a waiting list. A person can only buy 2 tickets attached to their name. In the menu the user can cancel an order. If the event was full and had people on the waiting list once a user cancels their order the person on the waiting list should get their place. I do this for a number of events with varying capacities.

Comment: Sorry, took so long.  I threw in a bunch of logic checks that you should look into.  If everything is good, you should just focus on the bottom portion, where I think you're having the most trouble

Comment: Sorry, late response, I'm in a totally different time zone.  Let me ask you, have you learned about class and objects, object oriented programming? It would make your problems a bit easier if you did?

Comment: no I haven't, what I believe is that I will have to pass waitingList[] through the method but now I'm trying to return a string [] as required but Im getting this error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]"

Comment: I don't know where you're talking about, but you should have your method signature return a `String[]` instead of the `String`.  Maybe something like this `public static String[] method(String[] waitingList){}`

Comment: That is how I have it, check I have updated the page

Comment: What line does the stack Trace point to, that the error occurs? `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]" `

Comment: The line where I'm trying to return the value,  return s;

Comment: Nevermind, I see.  You're trying to return a `String` from a method that is supposed to return a `String[]`.  Two different things.  One is a String, the other an Array of Strings.  Change that in your method signature and you should be good to go

Comment: can you show me beacause I  am  getting errors when calling the function now.

Comment: This is the new error i receive when calling the function "Multiple markers at this line
 - The method canceledOrder(String[], String[], String[], String[]) in the type Amway is not applicable for the arguments ()
 - The method canceledOrder(String[], String, String, String) in the type Amway is not applicable for the arguments (String[], String[], String[], 
  String[])"

Comment: The thing you have to understand is that String Arrays `String[]` are different from `String`s.  `waitingList[]` is a `StringArray`, When passing arguments to a method call, you have to make sure the arguments match.

Comment: Show me how you're trying to call the function.  Your call should look something link this `String someString = cancelledOrder(String[], String[], String[], String[]);`

Comment: canceledEvents = canceledOrder(waitingList[], waitingList1[],waitingList2[], waitingList3[]); That is how I am calling it

Comment: It points to a number of places I'm trying to update the page

Comment: I can only guess what's going on here.  I'm looking at your original source code, adn see that there is a `canceledOrder()` with no parameters.  I'm Assuming you used the method somewhere else in the code, That's where your problem lies. Since you changed the method from `canceledOrder()` to `cancelledOrder(String[], String[], String[], String[])`, trying to call `canceledOrder()` is now illegal.

Comment: I can see one time in your `main` method.  Why don't you create an overloaded `cancelledOrder()` method.  You can have a methods with the same name, but different parameters, that's method overloading

Comment: have two different methods `cancelledOrder()` exactly like you had before AND the new one you created `canceledOrder(String[], String[], String[], String])`.  That's the only thing I can think of, though not sure if that'll solve your problem. You can try it though

Comment: I would name the method `cancelOrder()` instead of `canceledOrder()` so as not to confuse things

Comment: Thank you for all your help, this project has been a killer.

Comment: I bet. As much as it was a killer for me, I could imagine how it was for you lol. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to find out if `canceledname` exists in `myStringList`, for that you'll have to traverse `myStringList` - no way around it.

```
for(String name : myStringList){
    if(name.equals(canceledname){
          // continue...
          k = waitingList[name];
          System.out.println("The new name is" + k);
          i++;
          name++;
    }
}
```

For that kind of comparison it would be better to save the names in a `Set` for example:

```
HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
// here you'll add the names to the hash-set
// using: names.add("whatever");
// ...

//and now:
if(names.get(canceledname) != null){
      // continue ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare ArrayList to String, instead use `contains` method to find if element exists in the ArrayList.

```
boolean isElementExists = myStringList.contains(canceledname);

if(isElementExists) {
   // other codes here
}
```

See the API: [ArrayList#contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)